# Selecionador Option predeterminada de una base de datos

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, formularios

tengo una tabla "puesto" esta tabla contiene los siguientes campos

```
id puesto
1  empleado 
2  director
3  programador
```

ya teniendo la ID correcpondiente al usuario y los datos contenidos  mediante un submith en `$id = $_GET['id'];` quiero que mi campo select muestre su valor segun el que le corresponde al usuario, ejemplo:

si Juan tiene en tabla "usuario" dentro del campo "puesto" el id = 2, que el  select muestre:

```
<option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $p['puesto']; ?></option>
```

o traducido

```
<option value="2">director</option>
```

Para lograr esto, e investigado lo siguiente :

```
<?php
$tabla_puesto =sqlsrv_query($conn, "select * from puesto");
//$conn contiene la conecion a la base de datos
$id = $_GET['id'];
//aqui obtengo el id que corresponde al usuario en este caso seria usuario=2
$sql_usuario= "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Id=$id ORDER BY Id ASC";
//consulta select para identificar BD
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql_usuario);
while($res = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
$puesto=$res['puesto'];
//muestro el valor de pesto 
$sql_puesto = sqlsrv_query($conn, "select * from puesto where id=$puesto");
                            if($c=sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_puesto)) {
                                $tabla_puesto_puesto=$c['puesto'];
                            } 
}
//aqui seleciono la tabla puesto y relaciono que el valor de id con el valor del puesto corespondiente a su id de puesto, igualamos y consegumos el puesto con $tabla_puesto_puesto
?>
```

en este punto ya tengo $tabla_puesto_puesto= director 
el select donde quiero que aparesca en la selecion el puesto esta mi verdadero problema es el siguiente :

```
<select>
        <?php foreach($tabla_puesto as $p):?>
<option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $p['puesto']; ?>
</option>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Este select no funciona pero me gustaria saber cual es el error o si hay alguna manera mas simple , espero haber descrito mi problema correctamente

Comment: un usuario puede tenerr varios puestos ?

Comment: hola srJJ, laentablemente no, la idea del select es que se limite su respuesta a solo una y que sea dentro de las opciones validas

Comment: bueno, ahi te deje un ejemplo basandome en tu codigo y hasta donde entendi que era lo que querias buscar, pruebalo y me cuentas, y si te ayudo marca la respues XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te dejo un ejemplo de como seria menos redundante, para no usar estructuras ciclicas...

```
<?php
    //$conn contiene la conecion a la base de datos
    $tabla_puesto =sqlsrv_query($conn, "select * from puesto");
    //aqui obtengo el id que corresponde al usuario en este caso seria usuario=2
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    //muestro el valor de pesto 
    $puesto=$res['puesto'];
    //consulta select para identificar BD
    $sql_usuario = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Id=$id ORDER BY Id ASC");
    //traer la info del puesto
    $sql_usuario = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_usuario);
    //se recuperan los valores
    $sql_puesto = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM puesto WHERE id=$puesto");
    //se trae la info del usuario
    $sql_puesto=sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_puesto);
    //se recuperan los valores

    //se valida si las dos consultas obtuvieron resultados
   if ($sql_puesto >0 && $sql_usuario 0) {
       $tabla_puesto_puesto=$res['puesto'];
   }

    //aqui seleciono la tabla puesto y relaciono que el valor de id con el valor del puesto corespondiente a su id de puesto, igualamos y consegumos el puesto con $tabla_puesto_puesto
?>
```

aqui esta el html en el cual esta otro error
**NOTA:** nose para que usas la tabla, pero si quieres que quede seleccionada en el puesto de el, entonces hacer un ternario con el id de y le pones `selected`

```
<select>
                                //tienes ":" y es ";"
        <?php foreach($tabla_puesto as $p):?>
<option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $p['puesto']; ?>
</option>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>}
```

espero te sirva Bro... ReNiceCode...

Comment: ya quedo (fue mas duro de lo que espere) es extraño pero al probar el ejerciciosin : causa error , creo que es algo normal en la sitacsis

Comment: es por lo que estas introduciendo una sentencia php dentro de codigo html. son errores de sintaxis que suelen dar solores de cabeza